# Confidential identity for more than 2 parties (> 3+)

Tags: corda

For confidential identity in a transaction that has 2 signees (parties) is trivial, but for 3 (or more)? Each time you run swapidentitiesFlow, a nonce is created such that the initiator of the flow (i.e. me) will always have a different key in face of its counterparty. For example initiator is Party A to start a Tx with Part B and C. Party A starts a swapidentity with Party B and another swapidentity with Party C. Party A will have 2 new identities each with party B and C. I have put that into the collectsignatures flow as myOptionalKeys, but i think Party B and C cannot resolve the identity between them. Any thoughts? How do i use Confidential Identity for Tx involving 3+ parties?

Answer (score 0):

An example of creating a transaction involving three different parties' confidential identities is shown below. The trick is to use only one of the two confidential identities generated by the initiator as part of the two initial calls to `SwapIdentitiesFlow`. You then need to show the confidential identity you choose to the party who didn't see it as part of the original exchange using `IdentitySyncFlow`.

**Our state**:

```
data class PartyState(val parties: List<AnonymousParty>) : ContractState {
    override val participants = parties
}
```

**Our contract**:

```
class PartyContract : Contract {
    companion object {
        val ID = "com.template.PartyContract"
    }

    object PartyCommand: CommandData

    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {}
}
```

**Our initiating flow**:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator(val alice: Party, val bob: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // Exchange anonymous identities with Alice.
        val aliceSession = initiateFlow(alice)
        val firstSwapIdentities = subFlow(SwapIdentitiesFlow(alice))
        val anonymousMe = firstSwapIdentities[ourIdentity]!!
        val anonymousAlice = firstSwapIdentities[alice]!!

        // Exchange anonymous identities with Bob.
        val bobSession = initiateFlow(bob)
        val secondSwapIdentities = subFlow(SwapIdentitiesFlow(bob))
        // We ignore our second generated anonymous identity. We've already
        // created one in the exchange with Alice.
        val anonymousBob = secondSwapIdentities[bob]!!

        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()
        val anonymousParties = listOf(anonymousMe, anonymousAlice, anonymousBob)
        val outputState = PartyState(anonymousParties)
        val command = PartyContract.PartyCommand
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addOutputState(outputState, PartyContract.ID)
                .addCommand(command, anonymousParties.map { it.owningKey })

        // Sign the transaction with our anonymous key.
        val stx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, anonymousMe.owningKey)

        // Sync identities with Bob. We already synced them with Alice as part
        // of SwapIdentitiesFlow.
        subFlow(IdentitySyncFlow.Send(bobSession, stx.tx))

        // Pass our new anonymous key into the CollectSignaturesFlow.
        val ftx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(stx, listOf(aliceSession, bobSession), listOf(anonymousMe.owningKey)))
        subFlow(FinalityFlow(ftx))
    }
}
```

**The first responder**:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class AliceResponder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val signTxFlow = object: SignTransactionFlow(counterpartySession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {}
        }

        subFlow(signTxFlow)
    }
}
```

**The second responder**:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class BobResponder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val signTxFlow = object: SignTransactionFlow(counterpartySession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {}
        }

        // Unlike Alice, Bob needs to sync identities with the initiator.
        subFlow(IdentitySyncFlow.Receive(counterpartySession))
        subFlow(signTxFlow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Yeah how does it resolves which @InitiatedBy to use? It seems to run into an error thrown by CordappLoader.kt when you try to run the flow with 2 counterparty flows though. Am I doing missing out something?

Comment: I had the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790458/how-can-i-test-two-different-responder-flows-in-the-same-cordapp.