# How can I test two different responder flows in the same CorDapp?

Tags: corda

I have the following series of flows:

- `Initiator`, my initiating flow
- `AliceFlow`, which one counterparty uses to respond to `Initiator`
- `BobFlow`, which the other counterparty uses to respond to `Initiator`

Normally, the two response flows would be defined in separate CorDapps. However, for testing purposes, I have defined them in the same file.

When I run flow tests, I get the error below. How can I fix this?

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.template.Initiator has been
>   specified as the initiating flow by both com.template.BobResponder and
>   com.template.AliceResponder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your responders in different packages. For example, if `AliceFlow` is defined in `com.template`, `BobFlow` could be defined in `com.template2`.

Then, in your flows, register both packages:

```
setCordappPackages("com.template", "com.template2")
```

Comment: Is this still true for Corda 3.3? Can it be worked around? Placing responders in different files is really inconvenient

Comment: this did not help. Still get `IllegalArgumentException: com.luxoft.poc.mobi.flow.BookingFlow has been specified as the initiating flow by both com.luxoft.poc.mobi.flow.booking.responder2.BankFreezeMoney and com.luxoft.poc.mobi.flow.booking.responder.TransportProviderBookStep`